# Deployment agent connection error in release management :Received Exception : System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I am trying to connect my Deployment agent  to RM client from different domain. I created a shadow account and all other .Still it is not working. I am able to connect with same domain. My RM client and server is in same machine (VM). and my deployment agent is in different workgroup domain.(everything is in VM's) I am getting below error from the log file.

```
   Created Nt account for user RM.user1
   Found Sid S-1-5-21-2704102820-366803756-3152234569-1011 for user RM.user1
   Is RM.user1 network service account? False 
   Created Nt account for user RM.user1
   Found Sid S-1-5-21-2704102820-366803756-3152234569-1011 for user RM.user1
   Is RM.user1 local system account? False 
   Domain: 
   Final UserName: SVWP500\RM.user1.
   Loading account details for SVWP500\RM.user1
   Is SVWP500\RM.user1 local machine account? True 
Normalized account is SVWP500\RM.user1 and Sid is S-1-5-21-2704102820-366803756-3152234569-1011
Validating account to use as identity for Release Management Services...
IsAdminAccount : Trying to determine if the account : SVWP500\RM.user1 is an admin on the local machine
IsAdminAccount : Trying to determine if the account : SVWP500\RM.user1 is an admin on the local machine
User SVWP500\RM.user1 is system, Admin 
Validated account to use as identity for Release Management Services.
Validating Release Management Server for Team Foundation Server 2013....


ServiceUserIsServiceUser="1" InstallerUserIsReleaseManager="1" />, Release Management Server for Team Foundation Server 2013 validation succeeded.


Received Exception : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.SetKeySetSecurityInfo(SafeProvHandle hProv, CryptoKeySecurity cryptoKeySecurity, AccessControlSections accessControlSections)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.CommonConfiguration.Helpers.CryptoHelper.<.ctor>b__2(CspParameters container)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.CommonConfiguration.Helpers.CryptoHelper.ConfigureDeployerCryptoKey(String userName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.CommonConfiguration.DeployerConfigurationManager.Configure()
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
Work completed for GetConfiguration() call : got out of turn error


Please help on this.
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the account you are using to register the deployment agent hasn't got the permission to access to release management. Because next step after Team Foundation Validation is updating deployment configuration.

```
I, 2015/02/13, 08:25:54.156, Release Management Server for Team Foundation Server 2013 validation succeeded.
I, 2015/02/13, 08:25:54.236, Updating Microsoft Deployment Agent 2013 configuration settings...
V, 2015/02/13, 08:25:54.238, Successfully read Release Management deployer registry key, installation path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\
V, 2015/02/13, 08:25:54.251, Opening configuration file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\bin\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.dll.config
```

I have a similar step up and below are the steps I did to make it work in my environment

1. Create a local user (RMServer) on both DomainA\RMServer & DomainB\DeploymentAgentServer machines. Add the users to administrators group
2. Create a local user (DeployAgent) on both DomainA\RMServer & DomainB\DeploymentAgentServer machines. Add the users to administrators group
3. From Release Management client add .\RMServer account and grant both "Service User" and "Release Manager"permissions (please note on windows account test box don't use machinename\user, just add .\user)
4. From Release Management client add .\DeployAgent account and grant "Service User" (please note on windows account text box don't use machinename\user, just add .\user)
5. Install the Deployment Agent on DomainB\DeploymentAgentServer as DeployAgent user (created in step 2)

I was using the [Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/12/configuring-release-management-to-work-across-untrusted.aspx) & [Wouter de Kort](http://wouterdekort.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/connecting-release-management-clients.html) blog

Comment: Thanks Bharath.. My RM client and server is in same machine.Currently I have same user in my server\Client and deployment agent..and I am configuring from that local user account. .Do I need to create 2 local users again. Can you please confirm.

Comment: Hi Abin,

Not sure if you have managed to sort out the issue. I was able to recreate the issue you are experiencing. I have documented the step and solution in the below link. Hope it helps.

http://bharathsundaresan.com/2015/02/configuring-release-management-deployment-agent-non-domain-server/